Can't add password to overlay form but can add username
Script that enters username and password in the sign in overlay form for website. Username field can be found via XPATH and text entered, password field can't be found via XPATH or ID, causes TimeoutException error.
Password field can be found via
password_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password')

but text can't be entered, causes ElementNotInteractableException error.
username_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="email"]')))
username_field.send_keys(username)

password_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="password"]')))
#password_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password')
password_field.send_keys(password)

sign_in_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="login-form"]')))
sign_in_button.click()

Tried entering just one character "1" for password, adding password_field.clear() and password_field.click() before send_keys. Any idea? Thanks everyone.

Have you looked at this site with the debugging tools?  There are four elements with the id "password".  The site is poorly written, so you will have to use a more explicit XPATH.

Issue: The website has multiple elements with same attributes(ID, NAME etc.). Issue is that your XPaths are locating multiple elements and trying to click or perform action on the first element which it locates from the top of the DOM.
Solution: You need to locate the specific element of your interest out of the multiple elements. For example:

//input[@id="email"] - this locates 2 elements, you need the first element. Change your XPath expression to (//input[@id='email'])[1]. The last part [1] indicates that it should locate the first element from the top of the DOM.
//*[@id="password"] - this locates 4 elements, you need the second one. Change the XPath to (//input[@id='password'])[2]

Refer the working code below:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.compensationrecovery.com/retail")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Click on Sign in element
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li//a[@id='btnSignInMain']"))).click()

# Send text to email address text box
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//input[@id='email'])[1]"))).send_keys("test@abc.com")

# Send text to password text box
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//input[@id='password'])[2]"))).send_keys("testPassword")

# Click on Sign In button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//button[text()='Sign In'])[1]"))).click()


Make sure to adjust the locator strategy based on HTML structure
username_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="email"]')))
username_field.send_keys(username)


try : 
    password_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'password')))
    #password_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'password')))

sign_in_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="login-form"]')))
sign_in_button.click()


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This doesn't work because there are 4 password fields on the page that match (By.NAME, 'password') and the one you need is not first.

The problem is that your locators are not finding only the element that you want, e.g. there are 4 elements on the page that match the ID "username" and 4 more that match the ID "password". This wouldn't necessarily be a problem except that the username field you want is not the first one found. So, Selenium is trying to interact with an element that is not visible so it throws the exception you saw.
The way to fix this is to make your locators more unique and/or make sure that the element you are looking for is the first one found.
The code below is working,
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

URL = "https://www.compensationrecovery.com/retail"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(URL)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnSignInMain"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#login-form #email"))).send_keys("email")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#login-form #password"))).send_keys("password")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Sign In']"))).click()


Suggestions...

You don't need to repeatedly create new WebDriverWait instances. Just create one, assign it to a variable wait, and reuse it to clean up your code, e.g.
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(...).click()
wait.until(...).send_keys()


If you are locating an element by ID, use By.ID instead of By.XPATH, e.g. you have
(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="email"]')

which should be
(By.ID, 'email')

It's shorter, simpler, and easier to read.

There are many options in expected_conditions aka EC. Make sure you are using the right one for the job. If you want to click an element, wait for clickable using EC.element_to_be_clickable(). If you want to interact with an element in some other way, wait for visible using EC.visibility_of_element_located().

If you aren't going to use an element more than once, there's no need to assign it to a variable, e.g.
username_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(...))
username_field.send_keys(username)

can be condensed to
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(...)).send_keys(username)


Prefer CSS selectors over XPath. CSS selectors have a simpler, easier to read syntax, are faster, and better supported by the browsers. XPaths have their place but they are only required when 1. locating an element by contained text and 2. doing complicated DOM traversal. You should prefer 1. IDs, 2. CSS selectors, and then only when required use 3. XPaths.


